# Counting text within tabular environments

Tags: tables, word-count

Does anyone know how I can count the words within tabular environments?

Comment: counting words is always fairly arbitrary but why can you not use whatever method you are using for words in section headings or parboxes or any other construct, the fact that the word is in a table should not make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

Environments `tabular` can be isolated by package `preview`. Then, other contents is thrown away, only `tabular`s are set:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%----------
\usepackage[active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment[[!]{tabular}
% Prevent hyphenation
\hyphenpenalty10000
\sloppy
%----------

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{tabular}{p{10cm}}
\toprule
Some text in a table\tabularnewline
\midrule
\lipsum[2]\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Then, the output file (e.g. PDF) can be converted to text (e.g., `pdftotext`) and the words can be counted by the method of your choice (e.g., `wc --words`).
I get 85 words for this example.

In general, tables can contain lots of different stuff (numbers, formulas, symbols, images, repeated table headers and footers, captions, ...). Before counting, the term "word" should be properly defined.

Answer (score 0):

A first thing to note is that counting words in tables might be tricky in case it is unclear what is counted as a word. For a table with pure text content, it might work well, but numbers and labels might easily get counted as words which might not be what you want. It's hard to make a good, general rule for how to count words in tables: in any case, it will depend on what kind of content the table holds.

In [TeXcount](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/), you can add rule for how to parse tables: by default they are not counted. For environments, you do this by inserting a comment `%TC:envir` in the document which TeXcount will take as an instruction to add a parsing rule for an environment:

```
%TC:envir tabular [ignore] word

\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
  \hline
  7C0 & hexadecimal \\
  3700 & octal \\ \cline{2-2}
  11111000000 & binary \\
  \hline \hline
  1984 & decimal \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

The rule means that the `tabular` environment takes a single argument which is ignores, and the content is counted as type `word`.

This will count the words together with the rest of the text. To count words in tables separately, you can make a separate counter for this purpose by using

```
%TC:newcounter tableword
%TC:envir tabular [ignore] tableword
```

instead.

Beware that TeXcount will also count the numbers/codes in the left column as words. Since tables may be hard to parse, and it might even be ambiguous what should be counted as words, you should verify that TeXcount actually counts the things you want to count. TeXcount gives colour coded output indicating which elements have been counted as words, which makes it possible to check this with relative ease.

TeXcount is a Perl script which most likely came along with you TeX installation. Alternatively, and perhaps more convenient for testing, you can use the [TeXcount web application](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/online.php).